# Android when keyboard open in dialog fragment it hides my buttons

Tags: android, keyboard, android-dialogfragment

In my app i open `dialog fragment`. In `dialog fragment` i have 2 `editText` and 4 `Buttons`, one on the tope where i close dialog and other 3 bellow. When i press edit button, keyboard shows and push up `editText` but hides  3 `buttons` bellow.
Here is 2 print screen of `dialog fragment`.

1. print screen is when i open `dialog`, and this is fine, just like i wanted, `dialog` opens, keyboard do not open.

[image]

2. In this print screen is the problem. I click edit button and keyboards open push up my `EditText` but it hides all 3 `buttons`, just like on the picture.

[image]

Here is my dialog XML code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_dialog">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_close"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dialog_text_naslov"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_close"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_et_drop"
            android:gravity="center"
             />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dialog_text_note"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_text_naslov"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_et_drop"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dialog_text_note"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
            android:text="Edit"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_completed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dialog_text_note"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_completed"
            android:text="Mark As Completed"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/dialog_text_note"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_save"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my `Dialog fragment` full java code but everything what i do with keyboard is when i click edit `button`, in this part and after click happens i call method `editDialogNoteText();` where i open keyboard:

```html
   case R.id.dialog_btn_edit:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Edit pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editDialogNoteText();
                break;
```

```html
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.petar.android.simplenote.adapters.ChangeNoteListener;
import com.petar.android.simplenote.beans.Drop;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

/**
 * Created by Petar_K on 8/31/2016.
 */
public class DialogNote extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageButton mBtnClose;
    private EditText mEditTextTitle;
    private EditText mEditTextNote;
    private Button mBtnEdit;
    private Button mBtnCompleted;
    private Button mBtnSave;
    private ChangeNoteListener mNotelistener;

    private RealmResults<Drop> mRealmResolts;
    private Realm mRealm;
    private RealmResults<Drop> mRealmResolts2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogTheme); //adding a theme
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_note, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mBtnClose = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        mEditTextTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text_naslov);
        mEditTextNote = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text_note);
        mBtnEdit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_edit);
        mBtnCompleted = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_completed);
        mBtnSave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_save);

        mBtnClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnCompleted.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnSave.setOnClickListener(this);

        Realm mRealm2 = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        mRealmResolts2 = mRealm2.where(Drop.class).findAllAsync();

        setTitleNoteTextToDialogNote();


    }

    private void setTitleNoteTextToDialogNote() {
        mEditTextNote.setEnabled(false);
        mEditTextTitle.setEnabled(false);
        Bundle argumetns = getArguments();
        int position = argumetns.getInt("POSITION");

        mEditTextTitle.setText(mRealmResolts2.get(position).getWhat());
        mEditTextNote.setText(mRealmResolts2.get(position).getWhat_note());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_close:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Closse pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.dialog_btn_edit:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Edit pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editDialogNoteText();
                break;
            case R.id.dialog_btn_completed:
                markAsCompleted();
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.dialog_btn_save:
                saveDialogNoteText();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Save pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }

    }

    private void saveDialogNoteText() {
        Bundle argumetns = getArguments();
        int position = argumetns.getInt("POSITION");
        String text = mEditTextNote.getText().toString();

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        mRealmResolts2 = realm.where(Drop.class).findAllAsync();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(mRealmResolts2.get(position)).setWhat_note(text);
        // mEditTextTitle.setText(mRealmResolts.get(position).getWhat());
        realm.commitTransaction();
        mEditTextNote.setText(text);
        mEditTextNote.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void editDialogNoteText() {
        mEditTextNote.setEnabled(true);
        int pos = mEditTextNote.getText().length();
        mEditTextNote.requestFocus();
        mEditTextNote.setSelection(pos);


        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(mEditTextNote, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);




    }

    private void markAsCompleted() {
        Bundle argumetns = getArguments();
        if (mNotelistener != null && argumetns != null) { 
            int position = argumetns.getInt("POSITION");
            mNotelistener.onComplete(position);

        }
    }

    public void setChangeNoteListener(ChangeNoteListener mChangeNoteListener, RealmResults<Drop> realmResults, Realm realm) {
        mNotelistener = mChangeNoteListener;
        mRealmResolts = realmResults; // not used 
        mRealm = realm; //not used 
    }


}
```

Comment: somone please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, but I would imagine that as soon as you have typed into the **EditText** what you want from the soft keyboard, and then press **Return**, the soft keyboard will disappear and your buttons will reappear.:)

Also, why is your soft keyboard setting

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE
```

and not

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE`?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you press back button buttons reappear but i somehow think it is more natural that buttons be above keyboard. Also, im using SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE because that way i can scroll the whole dialog, That way i can even scroll down to see buttons even when keybord ide them, i jsut scroll down and see them. If i use SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE i can not scroll down to see buttons when keyboard is open.